# MySQL JOIN + Max

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I need help writing a MySQL query. So far, none of the questions out there seem to fit my needs.

I have an `order` table and an `order_log` table. In the order_log table I make a record every time an order's status is changed. I need to display a list of the most recent status changes from the order_log table. The query I'm currently using does a JOIN on the two tables and grabs everything where order.status = order_log.status.

The problem with this is that some times an order will pass through the same status more than once. When that occurs, my query grabs every entry in the order_log table for that order and that status, but I only want the most recent log.

I tried writing a new JOIN query to grab the Max of the order_log date entry, but it's only returning 1 entry.  This is what I have.

```
SELECT *
FROM order_status_log AS l
JOIN orders AS o ON ( l.order_id = o.id )
WHERE l.status = o.status
AND l.date = (
    SELECT MAX( date )
    FROM order_status_log l2
   JOIN orders AS o2 ON ( l2.order_id = o2.id )
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do it, one is to have a separate subquery the gets the latest entry of each record: `order_ID`.

The result of the subquery is then joined back with the original table but has multiple conditions: that it matches the `order_ID` and also the latest `date`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    `order` a
        INNER JOIN order_log b
            ON  a.id = b.order_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT order_ID, MAX(date) max_date
            FROM order_log
            GROUP BY order_ID
        ) c on b.order_ID = c.order_ID AND
                b.date = c.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

That may help;

```
select olg.column1,o.column2,max(olg.date) from --You can add other columns as well
order_status_log olg
join orders o
on olg.id = o.order_id
group by olg.column1,o.column2
```